# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /membri/progettoditelematica2019/index.php on line 18

Tags: php, function

It is a university project that a friend and I are doing, but we are stuck.
There are also other files like:
cliente. php
connessione. php
fornitore. php
etc. etc

I can't put all the files and all the code here, but I think it's a trivial mistake that I can't see

the problem is here:
index.php

```
<?php
include 'connessione.php';

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["nickname"])){ 
    header("location: visualizzafatture.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST["submitx"])){ 
    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Utenti WHERE Nickname = ? AND Password = ?");
    $query2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Fornitore WHERE Nickname = ? AND Password = ?");


    $query->bind_param('ss',$nickname,$password);
    $query2->bind_param('ss',$nickname,$password);

    $query->execute();


    if($query->fetch()) {
        echo "Accesso consentito";
        $_SESSION["nickname"] = $nickname;
        $_SESSION["fornitore"] = false;
        header("location: visualizzafatture.php");
        exit();
    } 
    else{
        $query->close();
        $query2->execute();
        echo "Accesso rifiutato";
    }

    if($query2->fetch()){
        echo "Accesso consentito";
        $_SESSION["nickname"] = $nickname;
        $_SESSION["fornitore"] = true;

        header("location: visualizzafatture.php");
        exit();
    }

    else {
        echo "Accesso rifiutato";
    }

}
>?
```

file connessione.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', '123qwe', "Product_Master");

if ($mysqli->connect_error) { //connetto al database
    die('Errore di connessione (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
else {
    //echo '<center><p>' . 'Connesso. ' . $mysqli->host_info . '</p></center>';
}

class gestioneprodotti
{
}
```

file gestioneprofilo.php

```
<?php
include 'connessione.php';
//require_once 'sessioni.php';//include una volta sola il metodo sessioni
session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION["nickname"])){ //se risulta già un cookie loggato, entra
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
else if ($_SESSION["nickname"]!='root' && $_SESSION["fornitore"] == true){
    header("location: fornitore.php");
    exit();
}


?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a href="InVendita.php" style="float:right;">Torna agli acquisti</a>
    <br>
    <center>
        <h1>Benvenuto <?php echo $_SESSION['nickname']?></h1> 
        <h3>qui potrai modificare alcune delle tue informazioni base</h3>
    </center>
    <form action="gestioneprofilo.php" method="POST">
        <center>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nuovo username:</td><td><input type="text" name="nickname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nuovo email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nuovo indirizzo:</td><td><input type="text" name="indirizzo"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nuovo paese:</td><td><input type="text" name="paese"></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Nuovo numero:</td><td><input type="text" name="numero"></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>            
            <tr><td>cambia o conferma password:</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ripeti password:</td><td><input type="password" name="ripeti_password"></td></tr>                 
        </table>
        </center>
        <?php 

        if (isset($_POST["modifica"])){ //se è stato premuto il pulsante submitx, manda la query al db

            $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $indirizzo = $_POST['indirizzo'];
            $numero = $_POST['numero'];
            $paese = $_POST['paese'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $ripeti_password = $_POST['ripeti_password'];
            $query = "";
            if($password == $ripeti_password && !empty($password)){
                $query = "UPDATE Utenti SET ";

                if(!empty($nickname)){
                    $query .= "Nickname = '$nickname'". ", ";
                }   
                if(!empty($email)){
                    $query .= "Email = '$email'" . ", ";
                }
                if(!empty($indirizzo)){
                    $query .= "Indirizzo = '$indirizzo'" . ", ";
                }

                if(!empty($numero)){
                    $query .= "Telefono = '$numero'". ", ";
                }
                if(!empty($paese)){
                    $query .= "Paese = '$paese'". ", ";
                }
                if(!empty($password)){
                    $query .= "Password = '$password'". " ";
                }
                $nickS = $_SESSION['nickname'];
                $query .= "WHERE Nickname = '$nickS'";


                //echo $query;
                $queryCambiamento = $mysqli->query($query);
                echo "Tutte le modifiche sono state salvate!";


            }
            else{
                echo '<br>';
                echo "Devi inserire una password e farla coincidere!";
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }

        ?>

        <center><input type="submit" name="modifica" id="submit" value="modifica informazioni"></center>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

file cliente.php

```
<?php

class Cliente
{

    private $cod_cliente;
    private $nome_cliente;
    private $cognome_cliente;
    private $nickname;
    private $password;
    private $amministratore;
    private $email;
    private $indirizzo;
    private $paese;
    private $telefono;


    public function __construct ( $cod_cliente, $nome_cliente, $cognome_cliente, $nickname, $password, $amministratore, $email, $indirizzo, $paese, $telefono){

            $this->cod_cliente=$cod_cliente;
            $this->nome_cliente=$nome_cliente;
            $this->cognome_cliente=$cognome_cliente;
            $this->nickname=$nickname;
            $this->password=$password;
            $this->amministratore=$amministratore;
            $this->email=$email;
            $this->indirizzo=$indirizzo;
            $this->paese=$paese;
            $this->telefono=$telefono;

    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCod_cliente()
    {
        return $this->cod_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNome_cliente()
    {
        return $this->nome_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCognome_cliente()
    {
        return $this->cognome_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNickname()
    {
        return $this->nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAmministratore()
    {
        return $this->amministratore;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIndirizzo()
    {
        return $this->indirizzo;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPaese()
    {
        return $this->paese;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTelefono()
    {
        return $this->telefono;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $cod_cliente
     */
    public function setCod_cliente($cod_cliente)
    {
        $this->cod_cliente = $cod_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nome_cliente
     */
    public function setNome_cliente($nome_cliente)
    {
        $this->nome_cliente = $nome_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $cognome_cliente
     */
    public function setCognome_cliente($cognome_cliente)
    {
        $this->cognome_cliente = $cognome_cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nickname
     */
    public function setNickname($nickname)
    {
        $this->nickname = $nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $amministratore
     */
    public function setAmministratore($amministratore)
    {
        $this->amministratore = $amministratore;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $indirizzo
     */
    public function setIndirizzo($indirizzo)
    {
        $this->indirizzo = $indirizzo;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $paese
     */
    public function setPaese($paese)
    {
        $this->paese = $paese;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $telefono
     */
    public function setTelefono($telefono)
    {
        $this->telefono = $telefono;
    }



}
```

file fornitore.php

```
<?php

include 'connessione.php';

session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION["nickname"])) { // se risulta già un cookie loggato, entra
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
else if ($_SESSION["nickname"]!='root' && $_SESSION["fornitore"] == false){
    header("location: InVendita.php");
    exit();
}


if (isset($_POST["logout"])){
    $_SESSION = [];
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
        setcookie(session_name(),'',time()-50000);
    }

    session_destroy();

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

$myNick = $_SESSION["nickname"];
$id_fattura = rand(1000000, 9999999);
$queryCod_fornitore = $mysqli->query("SELECT Cod_Fornitore FROM Fornitore WHERE Nickname = '$myNick'");
$cod_fornitore = $queryCod_fornitore->fetch_row();
$cod_fornitore[0];

if (isset($_POST["aggiungi"])){

    //$id_fattura
    //$cod_fornitore[0]
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $quantita = $_POST['quantita'];
    $totale = $_POST['totale'];


    //qui ottengo il codice prodotto e la scorta di magazzino, necessaria per aggiornare successivamente il valore del prodotto rifornito
    $prodottoDaFornire = $_POST['prodottoDaFornire'];

    $queryCod_prodotto = $mysqli->query("SELECT Cod_Prodotto, Scorte_magazzino FROM Prodotto WHERE Nome = '$prodottoDaFornire'");
    $prodotto = $queryCod_prodotto->fetch_row();
    //$prodotto[0];//codice prodotto
    //$prodotto[1];//scorte magazzino

    if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Fattura_Dal_Fornitore (ID_Fattura, Cod_Fornitore, Data_Ordine, Totale) VALUES ('$id_fattura', '$cod_fornitore[0]', '$data', '$totale');")){
        die($mysqli->error);
    }
    if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Fornitura (ID_Fattura, Cod_Fornitore, Cod_Prodotto, Quantita) VALUES ('$id_fattura', '$cod_fornitore[0]', '$prodotto[0]', '$quantita');")){
        die($mysqli->error);

    }

    $nuovaQuantita = $prodotto[1] + $quantita;//la quantità viene aggiornata di conseguenza
    $queryAggiornaMagazzino = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Prodotto SET Scorte_Magazzino = '$nuovaQuantita' WHERE Prodotto.Cod_Prodotto = '$prodotto[0]'");


}

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="fornitore.php" method="POST">
  <center>
  <h1>Benvenuto <?php echo $_SESSION['nickname']?></h1> 
  <h3>qui potrai caricare le tue fatture</h3>

    <h4>Fattura:</h4>
    <table>


         <tr><td>Prodotto:</td><td>
        <select name="prodottoDaFornire">       
            <?php
            $queryCategorieAggiungi = $mysqli->query("SELECT Nome FROM Prodotto WHERE 1");
            while ($rowAggiungi = $queryCategorieAggiungi->fetch_row()) {
                    echo '<option>'.$rowAggiungi[0].'</option>';               
            }

            ?>

            </select>   
        <br></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Data ordine:</td><td><input type="date" name="data" value="2018-01-01"></td></tr>   
         <tr><td>Quantità</td><td><input type="text" name="quantita"></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Totale:</td><td><input type="text" name="totale"></td></tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" name="aggiungi" value="aggiungi fattura" />

    </center>
    <hr />

    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

have exceeded the maximum limit and it does not make me paste other code but I leave you my project site : [enter link description here](http://progettoditelematica2019.altervista.org/index.php)

sorry for the language I am Italian

Comment: Whats `var_dump($mysqli);` just before the first `->prepare` call? If its indeed `NULL`, then there you go. `$mysqli` is undefined in that file and you must import it to that file. If you're using a database class, you can have yourself a `getter` for instance.

Comment: Since you have `password` as a parameter to the select query, it tells me that you're not properly hashing the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Please show us the context of the posted code. We have _no clue_ which code is executed first, what scopes the code are executed in or anything. Currently, it's impossible for us to know where it goes wrong and why.

Comment: You probably forgot to include the connection file

Comment: Ok I tried to add

Comment: what  variable you are using to Create connection?

Comment: **$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', '123qwe', "Product_Master");**

Comment: Can you please also post the complete contents of `connessione.php`? Also, are those files located in the same folder?

Comment: You also have some other issues with your code. Currently, if `$query->fetch()` returns false, you're echoing something in the else block. Then, if `$query2->fetch()` is successful, you're doing a redirect using headers. However, all headers _must_ be set before you output _anything_. Once you have outputted something (using echo or even a space before the opening `<?php` tag) will result in a `headers already sent`-warning.

Comment: Magnus can you contact me in private?

Comment: my email is enzopoleo93@gmail.com